# SetImageBitmap Not Working in Android

Tags: android, image

I'm developing an app for Android, I'm using the Gallery widget, and I've resized it to fullscreen mode, so it displays one image at a time.

```
<com.example.librosapp.MyGallery 
        android:id="@+id/examplegallery" android:layout_width="1920px"
        android:layout_height="1020px"
        android:padding="0px"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20px"
        />
```

And here is a part of my Activity's code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

        //Here are my changes:
        File imgFile = new  File("sdcard/Libreria/0/0/0.JPG");
        if(imgFile.exists()){
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            //The app runs OK til here:
            imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            //BOOM! Exception
        }           

        imgView.setLayoutParams(new MyGallery.LayoutParams(1950, 1000));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        return imgView;
    }
```

I don't know which exception am I getting, because I can't debug here, I'm using the .APK in my device. (The only way that I have to debug this, is with the virtual device, and I donnow why it runs really slow.

**Am I doing something wrong?, that code works perfect if I use the same image, but as a project Resource (using setImageDrawable)**

Comment: "sdcard/Libreria/0/0/0.JPG".. are you sure about this path?

Comment: You are creating the dynamic image, where are you adding it to your layout container?

Comment: Activate "debugger" in your phones developer-settings and use a USB-cable to hook it up to your PC. Then, you can debug it via Eclipse.

Comment: Stine: Yep, Im sure about the path, it's going into the if, (I printed it in a textview)

Pragnani: It's the getView method of a gallery, it's into my ImageAdapter class, so it's called everytime and it adds itself.

Lukas: I'm developing for a ViewSonic VSD220, it's like an all-in-one, with Android. The problem is that I cannot find the USB drivers for Windows, and Windows doesn't recognize it as an available device. Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `imgView.invalidate()` before you return it.

Comment: Nope, still not working. :(

Comment: Can you post the top of the stack trace so we can see the exception?

Comment: Nick, I don't have stack trace, I cannot debug here.. I'm installing the APK directly on the device. As I explained before, I can't find my device USB drivers in order to use USB-debugging (it's a ViewSonic VSD220). And the Android Virtual Device is REALLY slow.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `myBitMap` is null.  `myBitMap` is null because the file path is invalid.  My guess would be the file path should be `/sdcard/Libreria/0/0/0.JPG`